# Filtering a DynamoDB scan by deeply nested value

Tags: javascript, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

I have a fairly nested object structure that I want to scan through in dynamodb. It looks something like this:

```
ProductGroup
| id
| customerId
| serviceId
| [assignedAssets] (An Array of Assets objects, each of which has the following)
| | id
| | sku
| | [instances] (an array of Instance objects, each of which has the following)
| | | id
| | | friendlyName
```

If I wanted to find the ProductGroup which contained an Instance whose id was, say "instance10", is there some combination of `in` and `=` operators that I could use to leverage Dynamo's filter expressions? Using the Javascript SDK if it makes any difference.

Comment: Simply, this can't be achievable using filterexpression in DynamoDB.

Comment: @notionquest any idea if there's a tool better suited to this pursuit?

Answer (score 0):

If you know the Asset ID as well, instead of using Arrays, you can use Maps to filter on the server side.

```
ProductGroup
| id
| customerId
| serviceId
| {assignedAssets} (A Map of Asset objects, where the key is id)
| | id
| | sku
| | {instances} (A Map of Instance objects, where the key is the id)
| | | id
| | | friendlyName
```

Here, the filter expression would be `attribute_exists(assignedAssets.#assignedAssetId.instances.#instanceId)`